# Многоязычность + mod_rewrite

Tags: mod_rewrite, php

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой вот проблемой:
Как с помощью mod_rewrite преобразовать к примеру 'test1.ru/cp.php?lang=`алиас языка`' в test1.ru/admin/ru'?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z])$ index.php?lang=$1 [L][QSA]
```

Попробуй так, должно работать